# Matrix Multiplication with CUDA, long execution time

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I'm new to CUDA, and I been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. CUDA is taking longer than just using the CPU to multiply a matrix. If I'm doing something wrong please let me know. 
Here is my code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#define size 100   // Matrix size
#define cols size   // Matrix width
#define rows size   // Matrix height

void checkCUDAError(const char *msg)
{
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if( cudaSuccess != err) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: %s: %s.\n", msg, cudaGetErrorString( err) );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }                         
}
__global__ void matrixMul( int *A, int *B, int *C)
{   
    int bx = blockIdx.x; // Block index
    int tx = threadIdx.x; // Thread index
    int ts = blockDim.x; // number of threads   
    // Declaration of the shared memory C element
    extern __shared__ int c_element_sum[];
    c_element_sum[tx] = A[tx+((bx/ts)*ts)] * B[(bx%ts)+(tx*ts)];

    //Block until all threads in the block have written their data to shared mem
    __syncthreads();

    int sum;
    for(int i=0; i<ts; i++){
        if(i==0){
            sum=c_element_sum[i];
        }
        else{
            sum+=c_element_sum[i];
        }
    }
    C[bx] = sum;

}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   //create timer.
   clock_t t1, t2;

   //start timer
   t1=clock();

   //allocate host memory for matrices
   unsigned int size_A = cols * rows;
   unsigned int mem_size_A = sizeof(int) * size_A;
   int* mA = (int*) malloc(mem_size_A);

   unsigned int size_B = cols * rows;
   unsigned int mem_size_B = sizeof(int) * size_B;
   int* mB = (int*) malloc(mem_size_B);

   unsigned int size_C = cols * rows;
   unsigned int mem_size_C = sizeof(int) * size_C;
   int* mC = (int*) malloc(mem_size_C);

   //initialize host memory
   for (int i = 0; i < size_A; ++i){
       mA[i] = 1;
       mB[i] = 1;
       mC[i] = 0;
   }

   // allocate device memory
   int* d_mA;
   int* d_mB;
   int* d_mC;
   cudaMalloc((void**) &d_mA, mem_size_A);
   cudaMalloc((void**) &d_mB, mem_size_B);
   cudaMalloc((void**) &d_mC, mem_size_C);

   //copy host memory to device (A and B)
   cudaMemcpy(d_mA, mA, mem_size_A, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpy(d_mB, mB, mem_size_B, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpy(d_mC, mC, mem_size_C, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   // setup execution parameters
   int numThreadsPerBlock = cols;
   int numBlocks = (cols * rows);
   int sharedMemSize = numThreadsPerBlock * sizeof(int);

   dim3 dimGrid(numBlocks);
   dim3 dimBlock(numThreadsPerBlock);

   // execute the kernel
   matrixMul <<< dimGrid, dimBlock, sharedMemSize >>>(d_mA, d_mB, d_mC);

   //Block until device has completed
   cudaThreadSynchronize();

   // check if kernel execution generated an error
   // Check for any CUDA errors
   checkCUDAError("kernel invocation");

   //copy result from device to host
   cudaMemcpy(mC, d_mC, mem_size_C, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

   // Check for any CUDA errors
   checkCUDAError("memcpy");

   //stop timer
   t2 = clock();

   //check results
   for (int i = 0; i < size_C; ++i){
       assert(mC[i] == cols);
   }

   //clean up memory
   free(mA);
   free(mB);
   free(mC);
   cudaFree(d_mA);
   cudaFree(d_mB);
   cudaFree(d_mC);

   printf("WITH CUDA - clocks: %d \n\n", t2-t1);

   //////////////////////////////
   ///////// CPU ONLY //////////
   /////////////////////////////

   //create timer.
   clock_t cpu_t1, cpu_t2;

   //start timer
   cpu_t1=clock();

   //allocate host memory for matrices
   unsigned int cpu_size_A = cols * rows;
   unsigned int cpu_mem_size_A = sizeof(int) * cpu_size_A;
   int* cpu_mA = (int*) malloc(cpu_mem_size_A);

   unsigned int cpu_size_B = cols * rows;
   unsigned int cpu_mem_size_B = sizeof(int) * cpu_size_B;
   int* cpu_mB = (int*) malloc(cpu_mem_size_B);

   unsigned int cpu_size_C = cols * rows;
   unsigned int cpu_mem_size_C = sizeof(int) * cpu_size_C;
   int* cpu_mC = (int*) malloc(cpu_mem_size_C);

   //initialize host memory
   for (int i = 0; i < cpu_size_A; ++i){
       cpu_mA[i] = 1;
       cpu_mB[i] = 1;
       cpu_mC[i] = 0;
   }

   int ts = cols;
   for(int bx=0; bx<(cols*rows);bx++){
       int sum = 0;
       for(int tx=0; tx<cols; tx++){
          sum += cpu_mA[tx+((bx/ts)*ts)] * cpu_mB[(bx%ts)+(tx*ts)];
       }
       cpu_mC[bx]=sum;
   }

   //stop timer
   cpu_t2 = clock();

   //check results
   for (int i = 0; i < cpu_size_C; ++i){
       assert(cpu_mC[i] == cols);
   }

   //clean up memory
   free(cpu_mA);
   free(cpu_mB);
   free(cpu_mC);

   printf("CPU ONLY - clocks: %d \n\n", cpu_t2-cpu_t1);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should mesure the memory right after calling your kernel, otherwise, you're taking into account the time taken to copy and allocate memory, which is pretty slow.

Comment: Is there any reason you're writing your own matrix multiplication routine? IIRC CUDA has this built in as a function for you to call.

Comment: @fontanini: thanks i will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: @Mike Bantegui: I wrote this as practice, in an attempt to teach myself CUDA on my time off, but thanks for the suggestion, i was not aware there was a built in function, that will  come in handy as start working on more complex stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your program, this is expected.  Your timer looks like it clocks the entire execution of the program, which would include copying to the device, computation time, and copying the results back.  Given the rather small workload you've provided for the program (100x100 matrices), the overhead of the memory copies far outweighs any computational benefit you get when doing the computation with the kernel.  Your kernel itself is also not the most efficient implementation.

I don't think you're doing anything *wrong*, it's just that you haven't provided a large enough chunk of work for the GPU and you could potentially further optimize your kernel.  Note that simply scaling up the size of the chunk may not significantly improve the performance with respect to the CPU, since you would also be scaling up the memory management time.  While it is relatively simple to write a first implementation of a program on CUDA, it is significantly more difficult to get good performance out of it.  The most effective way to use CUDA is to have a high ratio of compute to memory transactions.  For example, having a pipeline of several compute-intensive kernels to operate successively on a chunk of data, only needing host-device copying at the beginning and end.

If this is just a program to help you learn to code for CUDA, this is a great step and getting a deep understanding of how to optimize matrix multiplication kernels will serve you well in many other cases.  If you are writing this kernel for use in a production piece of software, I would recommend you use the highly-optimized linear algebra library CUBLAS: http://developer.nvidia.com/cublas (or some other library where the hard work has been done for you already).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it was very helpful. I wrote this program just as practice. I'm trying to teach myself CUDA and a bit more C while im at it, since college is doing a terrible job at teaching me anything of worth. I figure i better go learn a few things on my own, else i'll graduate with nothing but some half-assed taught Java, and a piece of paper that i'll be paying for years to come.

Comment: I always thought that the real purpose of College is to teach you how to teach yourself, so in that regards, seems to be doing ok.